# Understanding Appium Inspector log

Tags: appium

I am starting to use Appium and I am trying to open up the simulated device. However, I do not understand this message. It starts getting looped again and again. What am I missing for this one?

```
  Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' appium/build/lib/main.js --debug-log-spacing --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --platform-version "5.1" --app "/Users/wangeltamang/Downloads/AUT.apk" --avd "Nexus_S_API_19"

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.3

[Appium] Non-default server args:

[Appium]   debugLogSpacing: true
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '5.1'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/wangeltamang/Downloads/AUT.apk'
[Appium]   avd: 'Nexus_S_API_19'
[Appium] Deprecated server args:
[Appium]   --platform-name => --default-capabilities '{"platformName":"Android"}'
[Appium]   --platform-version => --default-capabilities '{"platformVersion":"5.1"}'
[Appium]   --automation-name => --default-capabilities '{"automationName":"Appium"}'

[Appium]   --app => --default-capabilities '{"app":"/Users/wangeltamang/Downloads/AUT.apk"}'
[Appium]   --avd => --default-capabilities '{"avd":"Nexus_S_API_19"}'
[Appium] Default capabilities, which will be added to each request unless overridden by desired capabilities:

[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'

[Appium]   platformVersion: '5.1'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/wangeltamang/Downloads/AUT.apk'
[Appium]   avd: 'Nexus_S_API_19'

[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of the log is showing Appium being launched. It starts off with showing the used command, then moves on to show the DesiredCapabilities for your launch.

```
  Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' appium/build/lib/main.js --debug-log-spacing --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --platform-version "5.1" --app "/Users/wangeltamang/Downloads/AUT.apk" --avd "Nexus_S_API_19"

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.3

[Appium] Non-default server args:

[Appium]   debugLogSpacing: true
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '5.1'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/wangeltamang/Downloads/AUT.apk'
[Appium]   avd: 'Nexus_S_API_19'
[Appium] Deprecated server args:
[Appium]   --platform-name => --default-capabilities '{"platformName":"Android"}'
[Appium]   --platform-version => --default-capabilities '{"platformVersion":"5.1"}'
[Appium]   --automation-name => --default-capabilities '{"automationName":"Appium"}'
```

Below that you can see the GET command to check for the server status, as well as the response from the command (which is the section that's looping).

```
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you should know about response codes in appium logs like

```
0 for success
```

`7 NoSuchElement` etc.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

After reading this webpage you will be able to easily understand appium logs

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are working with the GUI from the format of you appium log.

Make sure you select the "Prelaunch Application" in the General Settings

See screenshot[image: Settings Screenshot]